# Different behavior of sql server SSMS vs ODBC for BACKUP DATABASE

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I use Sql server Native client 11 for database programing. I use this command to create a full backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE [AminDB] TO DISK = 'E:\AminExe\Hogug02\BKUP\PYBKUPyy-13970515-1211-1.BAK' WITH INIT, COMPRESSION, NOSKIP;
```

When I execute this command in SSMS, I get this result:

Processed 175632 pages for database 'AminDB', file 'AminDB_dat' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'AminDB', file 'AminDB_log' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 175634 pages in 6.029 seconds (227.588 MB/sec).

When I execute this command using SqlExecDirect, I get SUCCESS_WITH_INFO and SQLGetDiagRec returns this result:

Processed 175632 pages for database 'AminDB', file 'AminDB_dat' on file 1.

and backup is not created.
for many other databases, executing backup database command always returns SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO, but the backup file randomly is created or not.
What should I do for my Application create successful backup?
thanks in advance
mr.abzadeh

Answer (score 0):

I called SQLMoreResults after BACKUP DATABASE statement repeatedly until it returned SQL_NO_DATA. This completely solved the problem.